# Making database mdf work across different computers

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I know this is kind of a stupid question but it gives me a lot of problems. Me and my partners in college projects have a lot of issues making the database mdf work when we send each other the visual studio projects. It gives us errors about the versions of sql server. Is the only solution to this to install same version of sql servers for the entire team or is there some other workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must be using the **same** version of SQL Server across all PC's.

You can ***never*** "go back" in time with a SQL Server database - once a `.mdf` file has been attached to a given version, it can ***never*** be attached to an older version anymore. And you cannot get around this by using the database compatibility level, either - the internal database file structures are just too different between versions, and no backwards "downgrade" path is provided.

One way to get around this would be to have a common, shared **server** somewhere that everyone can connect to and everyone can work with - making in unnecessary to send around "free-floating" `.mdf` files altogether... after all, it's SQL **Server** - a **server-based** system - not so much a file-based "database" system ....

Another way to go would be to stop sharing the **binary** `.mdf` file, but instead work with **SQL scripts** that you can exchange within your team, and that each team member can execute locally on their respective SQL Server instances - regardless of their local version

Comment: Well, another solution could be to create the database for an older version. Use the minimum version a person on your team has. A later version of SQL Server can then use this database, too.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: sure - but as soon as team member X has used that `.mdf` on a more recent version and made changes to it - it cannot go back to the team member Y with the older version  .....

Comment: Are you sure? If I use SQL Server 2012 to create an SQL Server 2008 database, will the format really change?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: you ***CANNOT*** create a `.mdf` in SQL Server 2012 that's usable in SQL Server 2008 - no amount of compatibility level or anything will work. The internal file structures are not dependent and not controlled by the compatibility level - trust me - I've tried this many times, with no success ever .....

Comment: So the compatibility level is just about the database features, not the file format? I never considered passing around mdf files, so I am actually asking out of curiosity.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: yes, exactly - the compatibility level controls which T-SQL features are supported (or not) - nothing else

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that instead of passing around mdf files, every person on your team creates the DB and then uses SQL scripts to create the objects. These scripts can be very easily created and exported from the SQL Server Management Studio.

This has the added bonus of being able to put the scripts under version control as part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I made such practice, with one way , by create separate pc running under windows server, only using as  sql server to store all data record , then the data is called  via "connectionStrings" of  IP with  server name of user policy, which is also secured  by password and username , so this practice is used , to enabled   two different programs to share that data , for example , that I made ( one web localhost app to create internal registration ),( the other web app using to access to mainpage via Login form).