# Portability of an MDF database file across different Windows machines

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, connection-string, portability

**Here's the context:** I'm writing a C# application that connects to a local database file (MDF). The application's GUI enables the users to do various queries and view results in a Grid View control. The MDF file is distributed with the application and can be considered an *immutable* (or read-only) resource i.e. not meant to be updated or modified by the end user.

The application is currently in alpha stage and has never been deployed. The source code, along with the MDF database, is source-controlled (via Perforce), so when other developers in my team synchronize their workspace, they get a copy of the MDF database (and LDF log) along with the code. No server connection is involved, all queries are made to the local DB copy using `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` and the default Windows Authentication.

**Here's my problem:** The MDF file cannot seem to be used anywhere but on the machine it was created on. If another developer builds my app on his computer, the connection to the local database fails with a generic `SQL Server error 5171`. However, the MDF file is *not* corrupted and is a *primary* DB file, so the error is elsewhere.

**Here's what I tried:**

- Verified that SQL server version is the same on all machines, so it's not a compatibility issue
- Connection string used in the application is dynamic (i.e. adapts to the location of the MDF file on the computer) and formatted as: `Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyLocation\DatabaseFile.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30`
- Used same Windows login on all computers, to no avail (still gives `error 5171`)
- Verified DB options with SQL Server Management Service: `Restrict Access` is set to `MULTI_USER`

The only workaround I found is to re-generate the whole database on the machine but that's not acceptable: can't one just connect to the MDF file one gets from Perforce and be done with it? Thanks.

Comment: The question that I found was closest to mine is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520640/making-database-mdf-work-across-different-computers but it does not quite answer my problem.

Comment: The most obvious possible cause is that Perforce (or your particular usage) is corrupting the file. Not certain what "regenerate the whole database" means but the phrase makes me wonder exactly how you store the database in the first place. For future reference, very few people have every error code generated by SQL Server memorized. Always post the complete and exact error message you encounter.

Comment: And one thought just occurred to me. Often when we retrieve a binary file from a SCCM the file is set to read-only. I'm guessing the database engine needs a writeable file even if you don't intend to update the contents.

Comment: @SMor Yes, I too thought about Perforce potentially mangling the MDF and/or the LDF file. But I'm not sure how to prove that. Currently, the MDF is saved in Perforce as a <text> and the LDF as a <binary>. These are the default types assigned by Perforce when I submitted the 1st time and I never changed that.

Comment: Text? I don't think so.

Comment: You have the MDF saved as text? Clearly it _is_ corrupted now. It needs to be binary. The simple way to check is to copy the perforce version over the top of your working one. I bet it stops working.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Sorry to revisit this post such a long time afterwards, but that indeed was my problem (i.e. saved MDF as text instead of binary in source control). I'm not sure why I did that initially... So thank you Nick, Mary and everyone else that contributed to this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question so late after it was initially posted, but here it is: the solution is to make sure the MDF file is saved in Perforce as **binary**, *not* as **text**.

That solved the data corruption problem right away and the MDF database finally became portable across machines/users without any further issue.

Comment: Returning to close questions with a detailed answer is a _good_ thing.